# SQL Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of charindex function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert MySQL query to MsSql query but I'm having trouble. Here is my query:

MySQL

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT count(books.id)
   FROM books
   WHERE books.status = 1
     AND FIND_IN_SET(categories.id, books.multiple_category_id)) AS book_count
   FROM categories, books
   WHERE categories.parent_id=0
     AND categories.status=1 ;
```

SQL I've tried

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT count(books.id)
   FROM books
   WHERE books.status = 1
     AND CHARINDEX(categories.id, books.multiple_category_id) > 0) AS book_count
   FROM categories, books
   WHERE categories.parent_id=0
     AND categories.status=1 ;
```

The errors I'm getting are:

```
Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of charindex function.
```

For reference.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ed19/3

does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this query. I just changed `categories.id` to `CAST(categories.id AS VARCHAR)`. Because the `id` is `integer` in `categories` table.

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT count(books.id)
   FROM books
   WHERE books.status = 1
     AND CHARINDEX(CAST(categories.id AS VARCHAR), books.multiple_category_id) > 0) AS book_count
FROM categories,
     books
WHERE categories.parent_id=0
  AND categories.status=1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time to answer it.. kudos

Comment: Any reason for downvoting ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT Count(books.id)
        FROM   books
        WHERE  books.status = 1
               AND ',' + books.multiple_category_id + ',' LIKE '%,' + cast(categories.id as varchar(50))+ ',%') AS book_count
FROM   categories,
       books
WHERE  categories.parent_id = 0
       AND categories.status = 1;
```

**Note :** There is a Cartesian product between `categories` and `books` table in your query. I guess you don't need `books` in `From` clause. Stop storing comma separated values in column it violates the First Normal Form

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%,' to data type int.

Comment: @Chinnu - Updated check now

Answer (score 1):

`MS-SQL`'s [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) function requires VARCHARs or NVARCHARs as parameters, so your categories.id should be converted to VARCHAR. Something like this:

```
CHARINDEX(CAST(categories.id AS VARCHAR(16)), books.multiple_category_id ) > 0 )
```

However, I would consider refactoring both tables and your query:

**1. Query refactoring**

As it is written, you can have false matches. E.g. `categories.id = 1` and your `multiple_category_id` is `'11,12'`. An alternative is to [split your string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string) is to have your condition like this:

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SplitString(books.multiple_category_id) WHERE Token = categories.id)
```

Also, * should be replaced with actually needed columns (in this case, it will bring all the columns in both tables). Something like this:

**2. Table refactoring**

Instead of parsing strings you should define an X table like this:

### categoryXbook

categoryId FK references category
bookId FK references book
PRIMARY KEY (categoryId, bookId)

so, that you can do your query using simple `JOIN`s instead of strings searches which can be slower (no indexes can be used).